# SaaS, develop REST or SOA architural style?

Tags: rest, soa, saas

I am starting a research how architectural style I will use, to build a medium CRM SaaS, many books authors recommends use SOA, but SOA can be complex, and REST is simple style. so what is your recommend?

Have any cases success with these 2 architectural styles with SaaS?

Comment: You have not provided nearly enough information about your project to be able to recommend the appropriate architectural style.  Maybe you could start by clarifying why your CRM SaaS will be different than the dozens of currently available solutions?

Comment: well, my corporate has a CRM, but is desktop application and i need migrate to cloud, in my country SaaS is not a alternative...and CEO's of my country, doesnt know CRM's salesforce or microsoft etc..exists a languange barrier, my corporate has a big piece of CRM marketshare, to defend this piece we will start a new product in cloud...about question, i only want know if have any sucess with these architetural styles...thx

Answer (score 1):

REST, hands down.

See [Chargify's API documentation](http://docs.chargify.com/api-coupons). They have a REST API. They are also able to use Cucumber scenarios (automated test scripts) *as the published developer documentation*. This is the best way to go.

Comment: Chargify would be more impressive if their documentation site was online, which it currently does not seem to be.

Comment: I have no problem browsing it.